# How to check if a value in dataframe satisfies a condition based on all or last few values in the column and replace it?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to check if the value in my dataframe is greater than 1.5 times the median of all previous values (or last 10 previous values) and replace it with the median of all previous values (or last 10 previous values). I have a huge dataset so i dont want to use loops.

```
  df
Out[315]: 
      a
0  15.0
1  16.0
2  13.5
3  14.6
4  15.0
5  26.0
6  12.0
7  28.0
8  12.0
9  29.0
```

i want the 26 to be replaced by median of previous values and so on. Once the value is replaced, i want the new value to be considered for calculating the median the next time. Here is what i  have tried:(for simplicity i have taken a condition of >20 and mean of past 2 values). Actually, i want the condition to compare the value to 1.5*median of previous 10 values and if greater, then replace it with the median of previous 10 values and the new value to be used next time the median is calculated.

```
df["b"] = df["a"]
df['b'] = np.where(df["b"]>20, df['b'].rolling(2).mean(), df["b"])
    df
Out[88]: 
      a     b
0  11.0  11.0
1  16.0  16.0
2  13.5  13.5
3  14.6  14.6
4  15.0  15.0
5  26.0  14.8
6  12.0  12.0
7  28.0  19.0
8  12.0  12.0
9  29.0  20.0
```

Here the replaced values are not getting used to caluclate the median next time. for eg. last value in df["b"] is 20 which is a mean of 28 and 12. But i want the value to be mean of 19 and 12  because 19 is the replaced value.

Comment: what do you mean `all previous values`, the previous means by index or by values?

Comment: previous values means values in previous rows or indexes. I have a time_series data. In my example, i want to replace 26 with the median of [15, 16, 13.5, 14.6, 15] because 26 is greater than 1.5 times the median of previous values. And when the value is replaced, i want to use the same logic again to replace 28 and then finally 29. Hope the question is clear.

Comment: So that would be median by index, and not by value. I think what @Ferris is asking is that, are you looking to sort the array first and then take the median (median by value), or are you planning on keeping the array as it is, and sort it only by the last 10 elements of interest (like what you have done in you comment, which would be median by index).

Comment: Also, does it really have to be median? If you just want to check if a given element is far away from it's preceding values, you can define the "far-off metric" as the mean of the last 10 elements which would make this problem much easier and also give you a faster execution time.

Comment: yes median by index.  i mentioned in my reply. Also i mentioned its a time series data. No sorting.

Comment: @Ananda it doesnt have to be median per se although it serves my purpose. But how would taking a mean instead of median make the execution faster.  I was hoping if i am able to put a condition based on previous values, i can experimant with the condition and try mean, median or any other outlier detection metric.

Comment: Because for finding the median by index, you need to sort the array many times, and sorting is expensive. And I am not sure if that's possible with any native numpy/pandas methods without looping. For finding mean for the last 10 values, you can easily use `np.convolve` (which should be highly optimised) to get the cumulative mean and use that to compare and replace.

Comment: @Amanda Makes sense. But i am curious on how to do it with median too. I may have to resort to using mean but still.  I will check out np.convolve. Thanks!

Comment: `median of all previous values or median of last 10 previous values`? both are quite different

Comment: @anky ok lets go with median of last 10 values. But once a value is replaced, i want to use the fresh value when median is calculated next time. I have tried taking a rolling median in the beginning and storing it elsewhere and replacing the outlier with the rolling median when the condition is met. it doesnt help as the rolling median calculated in the beginning doesnt factor in the replaced values.

Comment: @dataminer then i dont think it is achievable without a loop since you refer to the changed previous value every time.. Try a loop and may be use [numba](https://numba.pydata.org/) if possible to fasten things up. Also it is better to call out the exact requirement on the first time so people dont have to try different approaches each time the requirement changes in the question.

Comment: @anky you are right. I have elaborated a little in the question now.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [rolling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) with window of 10 and min_periods as 1 and get median. Shifting the values as just the median of previous values has to be considered

```
temp = df['a'].rolling(10, min_periods=1).median().shift(1)

0   NaN  
1    15.0
2    15.5
3    15.0
4    14.8
5    15.0
6    15.0
7    15.0
8    15.0
9    15.0
```

If val is greater than 1.5 times median, replacing the value. `df['a'] > 1.5 * temp` will be boolean index for where this condition holds

```
df.loc[df['a'] > 1.5 * temp, 'a'] = temp
df

    a
0   15.0
1   16.0
2   13.5
3   14.6
4   15.0
5   15.0
6   12.0
7   15.0
8   12.0
9   15.0
```

Comment: see, once the a value is replaced, i need to factor in the replaced value while calculating the median next time. That is not happening in your solution. I already tried something similar actually.

Comment: the **temp** has to be dynamic and keep updating as the values get updated.Let me try that

Comment: @dataminer if you dynamic update temp, It may not act performance than you use `for loop` to iteration the huge dataset and calculate the last 10 elements' median.

Comment: @Ferris yeah, i was hoping there was a workaround  in numpy or pandas to handle such a situation. To change the values on the go.

Comment: yeah, as @Ferris told, dynamically `temp` can't be updated using any of, numpy or pandas.